# Uploading files to django through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'm having trouble trying to upload files to django using ajax. The upload process is done in a modal.

Form

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="fileUploadModal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Upload File</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    {% crispy fileform %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal toggle

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#fileUploadModal" data-id="0" role="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">
   <i class="fa fa-fw fa-cloud-upload"></i>
     Upload File
</a>
```

This is how my file upload looks like

```
      $(document).ready(function(){
            var file = 0;

            $('#fileUploadModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
                file = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
                var form = $(e.currentTarget).find('form');

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'employee:ajax-file-upload' %}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $(form).serialize() + '&action=load&eid=' + employee + '&fid=' + file,

                    success: function(data) {
                        if (data['form_html']) {
                            $(form).html(data['form_html']);
                            $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
                                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            $(".container" ).on('click', '#submit-file-upload', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();

                var form = $(this).closest('form');

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'employee:ajax-file-upload' %}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $(form).serialize() + '&eid=' + employee + '&fid=' + file,

                    success: function(data) {
                        if (!(data['success'])) {
                            $(form).replaceWith(data['form_html']);
                            $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
                                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            location.reload();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

And my view looks like this

```
@json_view
@login_required
def ajax_file_upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        action = request.POST.get('action')
        fid = int(request.POST.get('fid'))
        eid = int(request.POST.get('eid'))
        employee = Employee.objects.get(id=eid)

        if action == 'load':
            try:
                file = File.objects.get(id=fid)
                form = FileForm(instance=file)
            except:
                form = FileForm()
            context = {} 
            context.update(csrf(request))
            form_html = render_crispy_form(form, context=context)
            return {'success': True, 'form_html': form_html}        
        else:
            if fid == 0:
                form = FileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
            else:
                file = File.objects.get(id=fid)
                form = FileForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=file)
            if form.is_valid():
                file = form.save(commit=False)
                file.employee = employee
                file.save()
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'File was successfully saved.')
                return {'success': True}

            context = {} 
            context.update(csrf(request)) 
            form_html = render_crispy_form(form, context=context)
            return {'success': False, 'form_html': form_html}
```

I really can't seem to get it to work. I can successfully get other data but not the file. When I click on submit, it refreshes and I get a 'This field is required' in the file upload section.

I hope you can help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Your ajax call is only posting the form data, not the file. I would suggest using a library (such as jquery.fileupload.js) to upload correctly a file, as it's quite a complex operation: you have to set the multipart/related body format, attache the file to your request as application/octet-stream, if it's large cut it into chunks etc etc... The django code looks fine at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is only posting the form data, not the file:

```
data: $(form).serialize() + '&action=load&eid=' + employee + '&fid=' + file
```

I would suggest using a library (such as [jquery.fileupload.js](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki) but there's plenty of other options) to upload correctly a file, as it's quite a complex operation: you have to set the multipart/related body format, attach the file to your request as application/octet-stream, if it's large cut it into chunks etc etc...

With jquery.fileupload for example, uploading the file is as simple as:

```
$(function() {$('#fileupload').fileupload({
     dataType: 'json',
     formData: $(form).serialize()...
     done: function(e, data) {
         ... your success handling code ...
     }
});});
```

where `$('#fileupload')` targets your file input field (`<input type='file'>`).

The django code looks fine at first glance.